# How to summarize the elements of the list each with each?

Tags: kotlin

In the given list of integers, non-negative numbers, determine whether there are a pair of numbers in the list, so that their sum is equal to the specified `number`.
If yes, return their indexes in the form of Pair  from smaller to larger.
If not, return `Pair (-1, -1)`.

```
fun findSumOfTwo(list: List<Int>, number: Int): Pair<Int, Int> {
    for (item in list) {
        for (digit in list - 1) {
            if (item + digit == number) return Pair (list[item], list [digit])
        }
    }
    return Pair (-1, -1)
}
```

I know that besides the fact that my code does not work, it is far from perfect. And I would like to get the most idiomatic solution from the point of view of the Kotlin language.

Comment: if you don't want a java solution, please remove that tag

Comment: I put this one because many Java developers know Kotlin very well and can help

Comment: if they know Kotlin very well, they would be watching the Kotlin tag as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is literally one of the most common interview questions.

Your current solution is has a time complexity of **O(N^2)** which is not good, however, it has a space complexity of **O(1)**, which is good.

Here is a working version of this approach:

```
fun findSumOfTwo(arr: IntArray, targetSum: Int): Pair<Int, Int> {
    if (arr.size < 2) return Pair(-1, -1)
    var sum: Int
    for (i in 0..arr.size - 2) {
        for (j in i + 1..arr.size - 1) {
            sum = arr[i] + arr[j]
            if (sum == targetSum)  {
                if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
                    return Pair(i, j)
                }
                return Pair(j, i)
            }
        }
    }
    return Pair(-1, -1)
}
```

After coding something similar to above your interviewer will most likely ask you to optimize the time complexity to **O(N)**, (space complexity will need to increase to **O(N)** but that is ok, time complexity is more important in most cases).

You can do that by using one pass using a **[HashMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/index.html)**:

```
fun findSumOfTwo(arr: IntArray, targetSum: Int): Pair<Int, Int> {
    if (arr.size < 2) return Pair(-1, -1)
    var map = HashMap<Int, Int>()
    for (i in 0..arr.size - 1) {
        var complement = targetSum - arr[i]
        if (map.containsKey(complement)) {
            var complementIndex = map.get(complement)!!
            if (arr[i] < complement) {
                return Pair(i, complementIndex)
            }
            return Pair(complementIndex, i)
        }
        map.put(arr[i], i)
    }
    return Pair(-1, -1)
}
```

*Note: That the above two solutions make two assumptions: 1) The input array is not sorted. 2) If there is more than one valid pair in the input array returning only one valid pair is ok.*

Answer (score 1):

Since you only care for one pair of indices which element's sum equals a certain number, use [forEachIndexed](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each-indexed.html):

```
fun findSumOfTwo(list: List<Int>, number: Int): Pair<Int, Int> {

   list.forEachIndexed { i1, e1 ->
        list.forEachIndexed { i2, e2 ->
            if(e1 + e2 == number) {
                return i1 to i2
            }
        }
    }

    return Pair (-1, -1)
}
```

Comment: @A.Rost what do you mean? If the list is empty, (-1, -1) will be returned.

Comment: `assertEquals(
                Pair(-1, -1),
                findSumOfTwo(emptyList(), 1)
        )` This JUnit test is failed with actual result (2, 2) instead of (-1, -1)

Comment: @A.Rost this is impossible. if list is empty, the loop will never run... resulting in returning Pair(-1, -1). see for yourself: https://pl.kotl.in/rysVn2bmE

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Very strange, that my JIdea throws an error.

Comment: I find an error. It doesn't work with `assertEquals(
                Pair(-1, -1),
                findSumOfTwo(listOf(1, 2, 3), 6)`. I apologize for misleading with an empty list

Comment: @A.Rost the result of findSumOfTwo(listOf(1, 2, 3), 6) is (2, 2) which is the index of 3, so it is correct if the same number can be referenced twice. If you don't want that the if expression should look like this if(e1 + e2 == number && i1 != i2), so no big change. see how short and concise it still is.

Answer (score -1):

(I just realize that this is NOT valid. So, plz skip this solution :( ) There are 2 comments here.

1. Imagine if `number = -2` and `list = listOf(-1)`. Then `Pair(-1, -1)` cannot tell us whether this pair is available in out `list`. Another thing is that Kotlin comes null safety feature. We can return it as nullable type, in this case, `Pair<Int, Int>?`. If our function returns null value, it means that there are no possible pair that we are looking for explicitly.
2. My alternative solution comes with concept of functional programming.

```
fun findSumOfTwo(list: List<Int>, number: Int): Pair<Int, Int>? {
    return list
            .flatMap { it1 -> list.map { it2 -> Pair(it1, it2) } }
            .firstOrNull { it.first + it.second == number }
}
```

Feel free to have discussion :)

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to add in the condition that only positive numbers are in the list. Already edit the question.